# jquery ajax just isn't working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ok, thats basically what i got. I also tried static values.

```
$('#submitForm').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

What i get as response is this:

```
Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText = "error"}
```

The php script (just a simple echo) runs as normal after that ajax call. What am i doing wrong? My submit script doesn't look all that wrong to me and i'm not doing XSS. : - (

My HTML Form looks like this:

```
<form action="http://dev.xxxxxxx.de/users/register" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-horizontal" id="submitForm">                <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputUsername">Nickname</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="inputUsername" value="" placeholder="Nickname" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">E-Mail</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="inputEmail" value="" placeholder="E-Mail" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Passwort</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" value="" placeholder="Passwort" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Account erstellen" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Can you post the form html

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do an ajax call cross-domain to me. Is the page you are viewing, and the PHP script you are hitting on the same domain? (same port, same domain, same sub-domain, everything?)

Comment: no, it's not crossdomain, everything is serverside.

Comment: The php of the form is not very helpful, can we see the rendered html please.

Comment: Have you tried not using an absolute URL? If you are using differing subdomains, that could be considered XSS as well.

Comment: Yeah, I still think this is a cross domain issue. I copy-pasted your code to a test file, and it worked perfectly fine. Like I said before, the target of the ajax call needs to be the same port, same domain, same sub-domain as the page you are viewing or it is not going to work.

Comment: Does modifiying your `action="..."` to `action="/users/register"` make any difference?

Comment: If it's a cross-domain issue, you would have an obvious error in your console. (not the one you logged, it would be red).

Comment: @KevinB The error he described is the exact error I get when I try to perform a cross domain request.

Comment: it was a preventDefault() issue. I thought submit() prevents by default, i was dead wrong.

Comment: This has already been solved, he was posting twice. Once with ajax, once with normal form post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the browser not to submit the form by default with:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

So:

```
$('#submitForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: this.method,
        url: this.action,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Otherwise, your form will submit according to the "action" attribute, before your AJAX returns.

Comment: Jquery api says, that submit() prevents form submission by default. Tried it anyway, doesn't work.

Comment: Can you paste the generated HTML instead of your source code from your template file.

Comment: I do not believe that it does prevent form submission by default: http://api.jquery.com/submit/ "This happens prior to the actual submission, so we can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false from our handler."

Comment: The default actions will still occur if you don't prevent them.  "In addition, the default submit action on the form will be fired, so the form will be submitted."

Comment: Thank you very much, it was cache. After clearing everything its working now. It's always those small things, which are making me older every day. Thanks guys for taking the time and patience !!!!

Comment: Also note that when getting the action and method, you shouldn't do `$(this).attr('action')` but rather simply `this.action` (same for method). You do, however, need to do `$(this).serialize()`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I love stackoverflow ... no wait, i love you guys!